# can not get key and value from dict python in a directory

Tags: python

I faced a problem when I tried to get the key and value from 
my file `wahbilogintest.py`, which contains a dictionary `kids{}`.

Can you please help me how I will search after my file `wahbilogintest.py` in directory `C:/webbplats/mydata` and iterate over in the file to get/bring key and value?

My source code

```
class visafilerIkatalogen :
    import os  
    folder = 'c:/webbplats/mydata/' 
    dinfil = raw_input("Enter your userprofile med prefix.txt: ")
    #dindictionary = raw_input("Enter your dictionary name: ")
    loginReadProfile = open(folder+str(dinfil),'r')
    for key, value in dinfil.iteritems():
            print 'Username is: ',key
            print 'value is: ',value

    print loginReadProfile.readlines()
    loginReadProfile.close()


Myobj12 = visafilerIkatalogen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file with `open()` gives you an `iterable` which yields a string for each row of the file. It does *not* give you an object on which you can call `.iteritems()`.

To access the python objects in the file you need to `import` it, not open it. One way to do this given your user input is:

```
import os
import sys

folder = 'c:/webbplats/mydata/'
dinfil = raw_input("Enter userprofile med prefix")
## Get the full path, the directory, and the filename
full_path = path.join(folder, dinfil)
path, filename = os.path.split(full_path)
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
## Add the directory to the sys.path and import the module
sys.path.append(path)
data_module = __import__(filename)
```

At this point you have a reference to a python `module`. You can access the names defined in this module using dotted notation. So, if there is a dictionary called 'kids' you can iterate over it's key/value pairs thus:

```
for key, value in data_module.kids.iteritems():
    print 'Username is: %s' % key
    print 'Value is %s': % value
```

You should seriously reconsider this approach to accessing per-user data. It's over complicated. There are likely to be plenty of better ways of doing it but without more info about what you are trying to achieve, I can't really help more.

There are also several things you can do to improve your code:

1. Your class should inherit from `object`
2. Import statements should (almost) always be outside the class definition
3. Use `sys.path.join()` to join parts of the file path

Comment: I got TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given), and tryed to fixed, but it doesnt work.